# Displaying external images/pdf in Sencha touch + Phonegap App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch + phonegap app for ios and android platforms.  Its kind on case management system where attachments are attached to cases.

I want to open the attachments (pdf/image) frm external URL.

Please suggest a way to do it in both the platforms. I tried window.open() but it doesnot work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do window.open() but remember to add the inAppBrowser permissions:

android (app/res/xml/config.xml)

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

ios (config.xml)

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
```

To add zomming:

```
window.open(URL, '_blank', 'location=no,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

if you r using phonegap 3 take a look at: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Another option is this PDF Viewer Panel: https://github.com/SunboX/st2_pdf_panel

Comment: Ok i made window.open() work but in android it doesnot open PDF files. Apart from this everything else seems to be working fine. Can you please suggest something .

Comment: Seems like in android (childbrowser/inappbrowser) is only possible to open local pdf files, not remotely. Did you try with the sencha panel I mention?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this will google docs - only for android pdfs.

Comment: I am getting into one more issue that is zooming in ipad. window.open opens a image streamed from webserver. In app browser doesnot allow it to be zoomed. I tried with enableViewportScale=yes also but it doesnot seem to be working

Comment: consider window.open(URL, '_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes') is available since phonegap 2.4

Comment: I tried this. But still I am not able to zoom on image which the URL has. FYI, URL is a servlet URL which returns image stream. I tried this in Ipad and I am using phonegap 2.9

Comment: I think it is enableViewportScale instead of EnableViewPortScale:
window.open(URL, '_blank', 'location=no,enableViewportScale=yes')

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same solution and I found that if you want to open a pdf remotely you may have to add google docs prefix, like

```
window.open("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + your_pdf_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Since I am using Sencha and Phonegap together, so this may involve navigation problem that there is no "done" or "back" button. When the "Back" button pressed, the pdf view is gone but the Sencha app would load again. That's another problem I am trying to solve.